# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null - I try to move data from "incompleteBookshelfList" to "completeBookshelfList

Tags: javascript

dom.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null.
**This error happened because I try to move data from "incompleteBookshelfList" to "completeBookshelfList".Please help me**

> this is my
> **dom.js**

```
function addTaskToCompleted(taskElement /* HTMLELement */ ) {
    const listCompleted = document.getElementById(COMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID);
    const JudulBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > h3").innerText;
    const PenulisBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;
    const TahunBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;

    const newBook = makeBook(JudulBuku, PenulisBuku, TahunBuku, true);

    const book = findBook(taskElement[BOOK_ITEMID]);
    book.isCompleted = true;
    newBook[BOOK_ITEMID] = book.id;

    listCompleted.append(newBook);
    taskElement.remove();

    updateDataToStorage();
}


function undoTaskFromCompleted(taskElement /* HTMLELement */ ) {
    const listUncompleted = document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID);
    const JudulBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > h3").innerText;
    const PenulisBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;
    const TahunBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;

    const newBook = makeBook(JudulBuku, PenulisBuku, TahunBuku, false);

    const book = findBook(taskElement[BOOK_ITEMID]);
    book.isCompleted = false;
    newBook[BOOK_ITEMID] = book.id;

    listUncompleted.append(newBook);
    taskElement.remove();

    updateDataToStorage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a LOT of code, try to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) next time.

Hovewer, the `taskElement` you are passing to the functions `addTaskToCompleted` and  `undoTaskFromCompleted` is a div that contains the two buttons, not the info about the book.

For the stuff you want to query, you have to look inside it's parent. I quick-fixed  *dom.js* but you may want to check your logic.

After fixing this, there are some more error comming up when clicking on buttons. If you need help with those, please improve/make a new (better) question. There is a lot of code and the language is not helping either.

```
function addTaskToCompleted(taskElement /* HTMLELement */ ) {
    const listCompleted = document.getElementById(COMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID);

    /******************* change HERE  */
    taskElement = taskElement.parentNode;

    const JudulBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > h3").innerText;
    const PenulisBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;
    const TahunBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;

    const newBook = makeBook(JudulBuku, PenulisBuku, TahunBuku, true);

    const book = findBook(taskElement[BOOK_ITEMID]);
    book.isCompleted = true;
    newBook[BOOK_ITEMID] = book.id;

    listCompleted.append(newBook);
    taskElement.remove();

    updateDataToStorage();
}


function undoTaskFromCompleted(taskElement /* HTMLELement */ ) {
    const listUncompleted = document.getElementById(UNCOMPLETED_LIST_BOOK_ID);

    /******************* change HERE  */
    taskElement = taskElement.parentNode;
 
    const JudulBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > h3").innerText;
    const PenulisBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;
    const TahunBuku = taskElement.querySelector(".book_item > p").innerText;

    const newBook = makeBook(JudulBuku, PenulisBuku, TahunBuku, false);

    const book = findBook(taskElement[BOOK_ITEMID]);
    book.isCompleted = false;
    newBook[BOOK_ITEMID] = book.id;

    listUncompleted.append(newBook);
    taskElement.remove();

    updateDataToStorage();
}
```